# Algorithm for quadratic form matrix multiplication with sparse matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am optimizing code which heavily relies on a custom made Matrix library, (which won't be excluded from the project because it is everywhere. This is not nice, but it's a fact...) Many calculations are done with matrices of 10-20 rows and columns, many computations include a quadratic form like

```
C = A*B*A'
```

I realized that often A is sparse and I would like to make use of this fact. So I am looking for an algorithm that would handle this case. Numerical stability is important. Is there anything I can use? (I didn't write our library so I don't know if there are any pitfalls I should take into account?)

As "our" simple O(n³) multiplication method executes faster than Eigen 3 on the target platform, as I need numerical stability and the matrices aren't very big, I guess that Strassen's algorithm as well as Coppersmith–Winograd algorithm aren't what I am looking for.  Instead it's just the quadratic form multiplication in a way that lets me easily check for zeros in A.

Comment: I just wonder who voted this for "close" ? I find this question perfectly valid and programming related.

Comment: I'm not sure you are going to get a lot of benefit from exploiting sparsity with matrices that small.

Answer (score 1):

There exists [this](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~zwick/papers/sparse.pdf) paper, dealing with fast sparse matrix multiplication. The developed algorithm divides the sparse matrix into two parts: A dense and a sparse and applies a fast multiplication algorithm on it. So for me it looks like that it does not dependson the size of the matrix, like you mentioned with respect to Strassen, but of the fact that it is sparse.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to implement a sparse matrix in ways that make in more condensed than a dense matrix. One way that I do it is as follows:

```
[0 0 0 0 0]
[0 1 2 0 9]
[0 0 0 2 0]
[0 1 0 0 0]
```

becomes a linear array of non-zero elements

```
typedef struct {
    int row;
    int col;
    double entry;
} Element;

typedef SparseMatrix Element*;
```

So the matrix now has a space complexity of O(n) instead of O(n^2)
For A*B, where A and B are matrices, you only need to traverse each array for matching elements (i.e. a->row == b->col && a->col == b->row ), and possibly add several together (inner product).
This algorithm would be of O(n^2) complexity rather than O(n^3). This is because you can skip the frivolous operation of taking an inner product that would result in zero.

Comment: Space is proportional to the number of nonzero elements, not the number of elements (n).

Answer (score 1):

check out Aydın Buluc, John R. Gilbert: [Highly Parallel Sparse Matrix-Matrix Multiplication](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.2183)